# Deploying Lucee application on Azure WebApps

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, azure-web-app-service, lucee

I'm a total newbie to Azure WebApps and I need some help.

I've created an Azure WebApp with Linux OS, Java 8 and Tomcat 9. I'm trying to deploy Mura application that's running on Lucee.

Taking bits from this example [Mura CMS on Azure WebApps](http://www.msclouddeveloper.com/mura-cms-on-azure-webapps/) which was done on Windows, I created a ROOT.war containing Mura's code and a WEB-INF folder containing a web.xml and lucee.jar.

I'm now trying to deploy the war file but it doesn't seem to be working.

I've FTP'ed the .war file to /home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ and the above source suggested magically the war file would be unpacked, not sure if this a Windows thing? That didn't happen.

I've tried many different options mentioned here [Deploy files to App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli) but nothing seems to be working.

I tried the following in [BASH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=api) and got this error *Couldn't read data from file "/home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT.war"* probably because in BASH that path doesn't exist.

```
curl -X POST -u <username> --data-binary @"/home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT.war" https://<appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/publish&type=war
```

AND

```
curl -X POST -v -u  <username> --data-binary @/home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT.war https://<appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/wardeploy
```

Another option was to do it via [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=powershell) retuning a similar error as above *Could not find a part of the path '/home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT.war'.*

```
Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName <groupName> -Name <appname> -ArchivePath /home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT.war
```

Another example I found it to deploy from a [storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=api). Running this creates a new file **app.war** with zero bytes to /home/site/wwwroot

```
curl -X POST -u <username> https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/publish -d '{"packageUri": "https://<storageName>.blob.core.windows.net/blob-container/ROOT.war?sv=2021-10-01&sb&sig=slk22f3UrS823n4kSh8Skjpa7Naj4CG3"}'
```

I then FTP'd a basic project, with the WEB-INF folder as mentioned above and a simple index.cfm page but I get a 500 error *Servlet.init() for servlet [CFMLServlet] threw exception*

I'm not sure if this is supposed to work on Linux OS, Java 8 and Tomcat 9 setup or if I should give in and try it out on a Windows machine.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to run the application successfully in your local?

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comment. Yes, application works perfectly fine on my machine but it's on a windows VM. That said, I know Lucee does work on Linux OS (https://docs.lucee.org/guides/installing-lucee/installation-linux.html), Lucee runs on Apache Tomcat on Java.

Comment: Can you try with Windows web app instead of Linux? Check if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mihansen/running-coldfusion-in-azure-webapp

Comment: The problem with using a windows machine is, currently you're not able to mount  storage to it hence why I'm exploring Linux as believe it is possible to achieve this. There is an option under setting>config>path mappings>New azure storage mount. That said, I just had a go at deploying this on a windows machine, took 10min and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @david-I Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members for similar issues.

> "The problem with using a windows machine is, currently you're not
> able to mount storage to it hence why I'm exploring Linux as believe
> it is possible to achieve this. There is an option under
> **setting>config>path mappings>New azure storage mount**. That said, I
> just had a go at deploying this on a windows machine, took 10min and
> it worked"

For more information please refer this [Azure Blog](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/tomcat/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using the following command via BASH. This was one of the commands I posted in my original post however, it wasn't just the username I need to add as per documentation but I also needed to add the password. Hope this helps anyone who is stuck on this. You can find the username/password under **Deployment Center** under the  **FTPS Credentials** tab or via **Overview** and download the **Get Publish profile**

```
curl -X POST -v -u  "\<username>:<password>" --data-binary @/home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT.war https://<appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/wardeploy
```